# can you help me to transform ∀x FO logical formula to it equivalent ¬∃ formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

i have this formula

```
∀x ∀y (A(x,y) V  A(y,x)  → B(x,c1) ∧ B(y,c2) ∧ c1≠c2)
```

to the equivalent formula that start by ¬∃x ¬∃ y ?

you will find the question here also

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018332/can-you-help-me-to-transform-forall-fo-logical-formula-to-it-equivalent-not-exis)

Comment: The original expression seems to be missing some parentheses. Should it perhaps be $$\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(A(x,y)\lor A(y,x)\to B(x,c_1)\land B(x,c_2)\land c_1\ne c_2\big)\;?$$

Comment: sorry , yes i forget the parentheses

Comment: What makes you think there is a $\neg\exists x\neg\exists y(\cdots)$ formulation? It would be easy to produce a $\neg\exists x\exists y(\cdots)$ variant -- $\forall x\forall y\varphi(x,y)$ is always equivalent to $\neg\exists x\exists y\neg\varphi(x,y)$ -- but your request changes how $y$ is quantified in an essential way.

Comment: actually i am looking for an equivalent formula to the above formula by using existential quantifier  ,so can you confirm the rule that you mentioned "∀x∀yφ(x,y) is always equivalent to ¬∃x∃y¬φ(x,y)"   ?  @ Henning Makholm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic equivalence you want to use is: $\forall \equiv \neg\exists\neg$.
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\forall x \forall y \,\phi(x,y) & \equiv \neg\exists x \neg \, \neg \exists y \neg\,\phi(x,y) \\
& \equiv \neg\exists x \exists y \,\neg\,\phi(x,y).
\end{align}$$